# Window Minimize/Maximize animations

Tags: silverlight, animation

Lets say I have a content region that can hold viewmodels/views implementing a certain interface.

Now I want to build something that looks like the windows task field thing. You can have several windows open. And if you Minimize one, I want the window to shrink and "fly" down to the task-pane. Just like when you minimize a window in Windows.

And ofc I want it to have a reverse animation again when you re-open it.

Is there any easy way to do this? (Using MVVMpattern if possible, if not, other solutions will have to do.)

Cheers,
E